# parsing a huge json file without increasing heap size

Tags: json, jackson, jvm, heap-memory

I have problem parsing a huge json file (200mb). At first i tried to use JACKSON to parse the json as a tree. However, i encountered heap size problem. For some reason, increasing heap size is not an option.

JSON format :

```
{ 
    "a1":{ "b1":{"c1":"somevalue", "c2":"somevalue"}, ... },
    "a2":{ "b1":{"c1":"somevalue"},"c3":"somevalue"}, ... },
    ....
}
```

what i want to do is to produce strings like

```
str1 = "{ "b1":{"c1":"somevalue", "c2":"somevalue"}, ... }"
str2 = "{ "b1":{"c3":"somevalue"},"c4":"somevalue"}, ... }"
```

Is there any way to do this without heap problem?

In python, there is simple way to do this and no heap problem(no JVM)

```
data  = json.loads(xxx)
for key,val in data.iteritems():
    puts val
```

some thoughts:
I might not need to use Jackson tree approach since i only want string.
Streaming Jackson might be an option, but i have difficulties write it because our json format is quite flexible. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: So, you're looking for a JSON streaming API, found one, but having difficulties using it. How could we help without seeing the code you tried and a clear description of the difficulties you're meeting?

Comment: If your result is string, why not parse string immediately. Can `regex` match you require?

Comment: @lichengwu Thanks! you advice is really helpful. Yes in fact i found i don't have to parse json, actually. I should use some pure string streaming approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using object-based data-binding is bit more memory-efficient, so if you can define Java classes to match the structure, that is much better way: faster, uses less memory.
But sometimes tree model is needed when the structure is not known in advance.

Streaming API can help, and you can also mix approaches: iterate over JSON tokens, and then use `JsonParser.readValueAs(MyType.class)` or `JsonParser.readValueAsTree()`.
This lets you only build in-memory tree or object for subset of JSON input.

Comment: Thanks! You advise is helpful. Here is some of my thoughts: Our data format is very flexible, unstructured, so I cannot define a schema or class for it.

Comment: By using a streaming approach, we can get a jsonparser from inputstream, while readValueAsTree is the same as tree method which will build a whole tree for the json string. The whole tree will consumes several times more memory than the original json

Comment: No, `JsonParser.readValueAsTree()` will not necessarily read the whole stream, but only a single value starting with token parser points to (or, if nothing, next token it will point to). If your stream consists of sequence of Objects or Arrays, you can read them one by one. So all you need to do is to advance `JsonParser` to first token of value (START_OBJECT or START_ARRAY), then read as tree.

Comment: One more possibility: you can also bind to `java.util.Map` or `java.util.List`, which will give "untyped" Object (Maps or Lists of values, quite similar to tree approach). This will not require custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use a streaming approach. I open a stream from http and each time read a fix amount of bytes to buffer. after I identify i have built a valid string in the buffer, i emit the string and truncate the buffer. In this way I use very few memory. Thanks!

Comment: In this way I am building a tree model for each small json string which uses fewer memory than building a whole tree for the whole json